# Why is a cast needed on generically defined return type?

Tags: typescript

Given this very simple property access function

```
export function accessProperty<T, K extends keyof T, P extends T[K]>(name: K, v: T): P {
    return v[name] as P
}
```

why is the cast `as P` needed?

I tried variations of it

```
export function accessProperty<T, K extends keyof T, P = T[K]>(name: K, v: T): P 
export function accessProperty<T, K extends keyof T, P extends T[K] = T[K]>(name: K, v: T): P
```

but all require the cast

Answer (score 1):

The way the generics are defined every `P` is a `T[K]`, but not necessarily every `T[K]` is a `P`. You can fix this by using `T[K]` directly.

I.e.

```
export function accessProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(name: K, v: T): T[K] {
    return v[name];
}
```